# How to Subtract a Number from a Column and Save Result as Vector in R

Tags: r

I am trying to do a couple things here in R. I have a large dataset. I need to find the mean of a column `SI.x`, which I have done, then break up the data and find the `SI.x` mean for each of the subsets, which I have also done.

But then I need to subtract the total mean `SI.x` (which I've called `meangen0a` as it's the mean of the generation I'm looking at) from each of the subsetted means. I'd like a way to save the subsetted means as a vector, subtract `meangen0a` from each of these, and save the result as another vector, as I will need to do more vector math later.

Here's what I've done so far:

1. I got the mean `SI.x` of the generation I'm looking at (which I called `gen0a`):

   ```
   meangen0a <- mean(gen0a$SI.x)
   ```

This worked fine.

2. I split up the generation by treatment (a control and four others) and only used those that were selected for (which was designated by a `1` in the `Select` column).

   ```
   gen0ameans <- with(gen0a[gen0a$Select == 1,], aggregate(SI.x, by=list(Generation, SelectTreatment), mean))
   colnames(gen0amean) <- c("Generation, "Treatment", "S")
   ```

This gave me a table with the generation (all `0a`), the five treatments, and what their respective `SI.x` means were. This is what I wanted.

3. Now I want to subtract the total mean `meangen0a` from each of the five treatment means in the `gen0ameans` table. I tried doing this:

   ```
   S0a <- lapply(gen0ameans$S, FUN=function(S) S-meangen0a)
   ```

and it gave me the correct numbers, but not in vector format. I need it to be in a vector of some sort because I will later need to subset the next generation and subtract `0a`'s means from the next generation's. When I tried to save `S0a` as a vector or matrix, it wasn't giving me a single row or column of the means like I'd like.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit - The mean of `gen0a` is -0.07267818.

The `gen0ameans` table looks like:

```
Generation
-----------------
0a

0a

0a

0a

0a

Treatment
-----------------
Control

Down1

Down2

Up1

Up2

S
-----------------
-0.07205068

-0.08288528

-0.08146745

-0.06296805

-0.06401943
```

When doing the `S0a` command from #3 above, it gives me:

```
[[1]]

[1] 0.0006274983

[[2]]

[1] -0.0102071

[[3]]

[1] -0.008789275

[[4]]

[1] 0.009710126

[[5]]

[1] 0.008658747
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: No need for the lapply, `gen0ameans$S-meangen0a` should be the desired vector result.

Comment: Sometimes `sapply` returns a vector. It has an argument with default `simplify = TRUE`. See its [help page](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html).

Comment: @akrun The mean for gen0a ("meangen0a") is -0.07267818. The gen0ameans table looks like (and sorry about the formatting I'm new to this): Column "Generation" with 0a 0a 0a 0a 0a, Column "Treatment" with control, down1, down2, up1, up2, and Column "S" with -0.07205068, -0.08288528, -0.08146745, -0.06296805, -0.06401943. When I do the "S0a" command in #3 in the original post, I get something like [[1]] next line [1] 0.0006274983 and then so on for 2-5. The numbers are correct.

Comment: @Dave2e holy crap you're right. That's amazing. Sorry I'm new to all of this! Thanks!

Comment: Sarah, please edit your original answer to include the data you provided in your comment in a readable format.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
gen0a %>%
     mutate(Meanval = mean(SI.x)) %>%
     filter(Select == 1) %>%
     group_by(Generation, SelectTreatment) %>%
     mutate(NewMean = mean(SI.x) - Meanval)
```